# Why is my friend notified everytime I comment on anything on Facebook

Tags: facebook

A friend tells me that they see notifications whenever I comment on anything, not just on their posts. Which sounds pretty annoying. 
I'm not in their close-friends list and they do not see this for any other friends. We don't even interact that much on Facebook.

I can't find notification settings relating to "notify when they post a comment" so what can they do? It's irritating for them and a bit creepy for me FB is deciding to notify one person of every single thing I do.

Answer (score 1):

The site [HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/260047/how-to-get-facebook-and-email-notifications-whenever-your-friends-post-anything/) gives a fairly detailed description of how to turn these notifications *on*, and you can go through the same steps to turn them off.

Your friend should check the following:
1. Go to *your* Facebook page (not theirs)
2. Click the Friends button on your cover photo
[image: Friends button]
3. Click "Get Notifications" so that there is NOT a check mark next to it.
Done.

Note that Facebook has several ways to set up notifications, so this may not be the only step required to fix the issue, but the others described in HowToGeek should do it.